# sql remove seconds and milliseconds

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 problems (similar to each other)

Problem 1:

I have a column in my table named dateofstart.

```
2017-09-13 09:55:02.000 
2017-09-03 09:33:12.000
```

I need to convert it to

```
2017-09-13 09:55
2017-09-03 09:33
```

The problem 2 is the date format is a little bit different.(another table/column)

```
2017-9-13 09:55:02.000 
2017-9-3 09:33:12.000
```

how can I convert those to without seconds and ms

I have tried some related questions on SO. but failed
some of them removed last numbers or allowed certain chars (the problem is I have 2 different formats)

There is a reason why they use different formats(something with the application) but now I have a problem where I have 2 find an answer that will work for both of them

Comment: Problem column data types?

Answer (score 0):

probably this can help you i guess.
Write this query in the inner query,

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(column_name, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i') FROM tablename;
```